# Определить формат бинарного HTTP запроса

Tags: binary

Подскажите, как определить формат бинарной строки передающейся к серверу по HTTP. По всей вероятности это JSON, так как в ответ на запрос приходит json. Строка начинается с 0x1A 0x7B 0xC3... Так же в строке множество повторений 0xC2 и 0xC3. Возможно вы встречались с этим форматом и сможете мне помочь.

Comment: может выложите чуточку больше данных? или так суперсекретные документы? Также неплохо указать, что за сервер используется.

Comment: Дайте угадаю, это вконтакт? Тогда скорее всего это сериализация [Type Language](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/TL).